# Formal deductions on Hilbert system

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I have proved {(α→β),(β →γ)}  ⊢ (α→γ) } using formal deductions using Modus Ponens and the three axiom of H2 : 
A1: A -> (B-> A)
A2: (A-> (B->C)) -> ((A-> B) -> ( A -> C)) 
A3: (( ¬ A) -> ( ¬B)) -> ( B -> A)

However now my professor is asking me to prove : 
 (1) (α→β) ⊢ (β →γ)→(α→γ)
and (2) ⊢ (α→β)->((β →γ)→(α→γ)). I am stuck on it since proving their existence with the deduction theorem is not enough. I must use formal deductions, any help for this ? Thank you

Comment: You should review the proof of the deduction theorem.  The proof is a transform to convert proofs of the form $A,B \vdash C$ to proofs of the form $A \vdash B \Rightarrow C$.  Take your proof you have, then apply the transform.  One time will give you (1), and two times will give you (2).

Comment: @DanielV Yeah, in my original answer I had done that conversion, but to convert that one again I would have ended up with quite a monster, so fortunately I found a much quicker way to do both.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's call your first proven pattern HS (for Hypothetical Syllogism).  We can nicely exploit that one for the next two. First, let's prove $\vdash (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$:

1. $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C))$  Axiom 1
2. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$  Axiom 2
3. $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$  HS 1,2
4. $((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))) \rightarrow (((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)))$ Axiom 2
5. $((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ MP 3,4
6. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B))$ Axiom 1
7. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ HS 5,6

This makes the proof of $\vdash (B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ trivial:

1. $A \rightarrow B$ Assumption
2. $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ (we just proved this)
3. $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ MP 1,2

Comment: Coud you clarify what you did on line 4 ? did you mean to write HS 2,3?

Comment: @johndoe Yeah, my fault. But, I found a better proof (for both now!) in the meantime ... see Answer.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you proved  ⊢(B→C)→((A→B)→(A→C)) , what I had to prove was  (A→B) ⊢ (B →C)→(A→C) and (2) ⊢ (A→B)->((B →C)→(A→C))

Comment: @johndoe I proved $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ on line 3 ... just so I could prove $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$ in a few more lines. Line 7 has your desired result. Since there are no premises for this derivation, it is a proof of $\vdash (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$. The second derivation starts with $A \rightarrow B$ as a premise, so that one proves $(A \rightarrow B) \vdash (B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you !